# How To Enable dbms_output in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I know it's a simple thing but I can't seem to find a solution, how do I enable dbms_output in [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/wp/inhoud/uploads/plside.png). From googling all I got was how to enable it in sql developer but thats not what I'm looking for...
I thought it should be automatically enabled in PL/SQL Developer but for example this block outputs nothing for me.

```
declare
  v_sample employees.first_name%type;
begin
  select first_name 
  into v_sample
  from employees
  where employee_id = 100;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_sample);
end;
```

Comment: just issue `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` at the beginning of your code(*from the command line*). Alternatively `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE()` might be used also. (Have a look at the `Output` tab)

Comment: thanks for answer but I'm getting ORA-00922 missing or invalid option error on SERVEROUTPUT. Do you have idea why is it so?

Comment: that case is not used within **SQL Window**, but from the command line. Get rid of that and look at the **Output** tab please( or **DBMS Output** of **Test window** ). Do you see the result of the select statement ?

Comment: Ok, my bad. It does work in command line. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome. Have a nice study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PL/SQL Developer automatically retrieves DBMS_OUTPUT and you don't have to do anything extra to retrieve it. You do not need to use a Command Window to see output. (And you should generally avoid the Command Window - it's a terrible way to program.)

Go to Configure --> Preferences --> Oracle --> Output, and ensure that the "Enabled" button is checked:
[image]

Another possibility is that the FIRST_NAME value is null and there is nothing to output. To avoid that confusion, I typically add a hard-coded value before outputting variables:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || v_sample);
```